# Jquery childs active when parent is active

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get the childs active when the parent is active. 
So far i have done this, and sorry for the lamme code i a newbie.
I am testing the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/MS5DV/3/

```
var toggleSlide = function() {
$("#slider span.active").removeClass().next().add("#slider span:first").last().addClass("active"); 
};
setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
$("#slider .active a#open span").addClass("ready");
setInterval ( function(){ $("#slider .active a#open span").removeClass()}, 50);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code

```
var toggleSlide = function() {
    $("#slider span").find('span').removeClass('active');
    $("#slider span.active").removeClass().next().add("#slider span:first").last().addClass("active").find('span').addClass('active'); 
};
setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
$("#slider .active a#open span").addClass("ready");
```

Comment: EY, thanks for the fast reply, but the children are not active when the parent is active :(

Comment: The first child is but it stays active when the parent is not active. :/

Comment: here is the working example [http://jsfiddle.net/MS5DV/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/MS5DV/7/).
Did you want all children to be active?

Comment: The objective is when the first span is active, the child span is active too, but when it is not, then the child is not too. Can i explain it right? sorry to bother and thank you a lot.

Comment: Ey i have done it!!  Here is the solution based on yours. http://jsfiddle.net/MS5DV/6/

Comment: ok then just replace the `span` instead of `a` and replace `find` intead `children`
`var toggleSlide = function() {
    $("#slider span").find('span').removeClass('active');
    $("#slider span.active").removeClass().next().add("#slider span:first").last().addClass("active").find('span').addClass('active'); 
};
setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
$("#slider .active a#open span").addClass("ready");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var toggleSlide = function() {
$("#slider span").children('a').children('span').removeClass('ready');
$("#slider span.active").removeClass().next().add("#slider    span:first").last().addClass("active").children('a').children('span').addClass('ready'); 
};
setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
$("#slider .active a#open span").addClass("ready");​
```

That´s what i wanted, thanks you guys!